# How to import new library in Angular2?

Tags: dom, service, import, angular, rxjs

I want to use [RxJS-DOM](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS-DOM) library to parse json data from file. I have some difficulties with including this library to Angular2 application. First, i installed `RxJS-DOM` with NPM. And i need to import this library to my service file with `import` expression.

`import {name} from 'path/to'`

How can i know which `name` and which `path` to use to import this library by analogy with, for example, `import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'` ?

Do i need to include this library in `index.html` like this and why ?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you need that for json parsing? You can do `JSON.parse(jsonstring)`.

Comment: I have a config.json external file with application settings and i need to get it's content. And on this example i want to know how to import any new library to my app.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's SystemJS, which is loading up modules for you. You're configuring it with a `systemjs.config.js` file or inline in your `index.html`. There you tell it to load packages from your `node_modules` folder and with which name you want to register it and so on.

If you're using the Angular 2 Quickstart project, and the Beta version of Angular 2, then the configuration is probably done in your `index.html` and rather minimal at that. You will find, that every extra NodeJS module you want to use, you have to import with a `<script>` tag. (That's not the case if you go the [SystemJS config](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) route)

So your base path it usually the `node_modules` folder, when you're importing in your TypeScript file. If you want to import "local" files that are not modules from your `node_modules` folder, you do that with

```
import {class} from './path/file';
```

---

Regarding your JSON problem - I would leverage Angular's `Http` class to read in JSON files like this:

```
interface IConfig {
    thingEnabled: boolean;
    otherStuff: string;
}

[...]

this.http.get('./config.json')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((res: IConfig) => {
        // do something with the already deserialized JSON here
        console.log(res.otherStuff);
    });
```

Comment: I have a solution with http.get() [http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/13_6_2016/17/gx2kJ3aUBkSerivPGAVaHg.jpg](http://data3.floomby.com/files/share/13_6_2016/17/gx2kJ3aUBkSerivPGAVaHg.jpg), but i wanted to rewrite it with rx.DOM.get();

Comment: I don't really understand the pro's you're expecting to get out of RxJs-DOM.

Comment: I wanted to learn how to import new libraries to Angular2 with example of Rx-DOM.